# Wordepress 4.3 won't allow new posts

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.3

Downloaded WordPress 4.3 last week and it was great. As of yesterday it won't allow me to type in the text box to create the body of a post. I can only type in the title bar.

I am desperate and have searched high and low for a solution with no avail. Please help?

Thank you.